# Fetching npm module from GitHub brings ".git" folder

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

I recently forked an npm package and updated it for my needs. Then, I changed the dependency on `packages.json` to point to my GitHub repo, and it worked fine. But, when npm installed the module, it brought also the git folder (`.git`). Because of that, when I try to install anything else, npm gives me this error:

```
npm ERR! path /node_modules/react-native-static-server
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! git /node_modules/react-native-static-server: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git /node_modules/react-native-static-server
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I avoid the `.git` folder from being downloaded?

You can check the repo here: https://github.com/dccarmo/react-native-static-server

EDIT

The dependency in my `packages.json`:

`"react-native-static-server": "dccarmo/react-native-static-server"`

Comment: `"react-native-static-server": "https://github.com/dccarmo/react-native-static-server/tarball/master"`, with the tarball stuff at the end doesn't download the git folder for me. I don't know why though, so I won't write it as an answer. Just pointing it to the github repo downloaded the .git direcetory.

Comment: @MikaS interesting finding! I might do that as a temporary fix. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have same issue. For some reason npm is not applying `.gitignore` as/and `.npmignore`. There is a similar issue with publish thou https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19073 (npm included my .git directory)

Comment: @Stamos oh ok, good to know it's not just me!

Comment: @Stamos please answer the question so I can give you proper credits.

Comment: I dont believe i answered your question. We should wait to see if someone fixes this or have the same issue and if there is a workaround. @MikaS comment seems like a good answer but still not 100% correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an old question, but I was running into the same thing today.
I am rather new to git and npm, but I did find something that may be of help to someone.

If the git repo does **not** have a .gitignore, the .git folder is not downloaded / created.

If the git repo does have a .gitignore, the .git folder is downloaded / created.

I had two repos, one without a .gitignore (because when I made it I was not aware of what .gitignore was or did), and one with a .gitignore. I included both as npm packages in a project, and noticed that the one without the .gitignore was not giving me the EISGIT error (because of the .git folder).

So, after I found this question, I removed the .gitignore from that repo and now it too does not create a .git folder.

Later on, I discovered that adding both a .gitignore and a .npmignore to the project now stops the .git folder from appearing. I did **not** add .git in my .npmignore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This seems to be a known issue with npm, and apparently it hasn't been fixed yet. I like your solution so I'm going to accept it, since it kinda includes the solution I had to do.